# Where can I find a 2.3.6 stock ROM for Nexus S (i9020)?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-android, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, downgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I've installed a hacked version of ICS three weeks ago or so and now I want to switch to the stock 4.0.3 ROM. As it needs the 2.3.6 stock ROM, I'll have to downgrade to it so that I can install ICS again.

I've found a 2.3.3 on ROM Manager. I know it may be possible to update from it to 2.3.6, but I'd like a direct approach.

I have a Nexus S (i9020), bootloader unlocked, clockworkmod recovery installed, rooted, with a hacked version of 4.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of downloads can usually be found on the XDA-Developers forum. Usually the stock ROMs are in the "General" section of the device forums and custom ROMs are in "Development". Check out [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1063664) for a pretty comprehensive collection of stock ROMs.